# How do I solve error message "an error occurred registering this project with source control" when loading a project retrieved from a TFS server?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs, ide

The full error message is:

> The Project 'my.project.name' is under source control. An error
> occurred registering this project with source control. It is
> recommended that you do not make any changes to this project.

It seems that I can make the error message go away, and load the project correctly by opening the csproj file, and remove all nodes with names starting with "scc" - however, then I have to confirm wanting to use the solution Source control settings every time I open the solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem: We ended up solving it taking a backup of the project, removing the project from the solution, checking the solution into source control without it, and then adding the project again.

Luckily it was a new small project, with very little history - I would hate having to do this with a large old project...

I would probably try tbergstedt's suggestion first, if I where you.

Answer (score 92):

Please open the *.csproj file of your project then replace the following tags:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

With

```
<SccProjectName>
</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>
</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>
</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>
</SccProvider>
```

Close the solution, close VS, reopen VS and then your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Can we elaborate on this a little bit? "Scc" is "SouceControlSomething" and SAK is... what, directing visual studio to go to TFS's... SAK? Can somebody out there who is connected with Visual Studios built-in source control facilities tell me what the values are for these elements?

Comment: They can be set by other Source Control Providers. I resolved my issue by removing SVN from these tags, as the project had previously been under another Source Control System (in this case Tortoise SVN).

Comment: When I tried to open the .csproj file it comes up with an error saying the system can not find the file specified depite the fact i just double clicked it to open

Comment: You should open the .csproj file with text editor ( notepad,..)

Comment: I just had this issue for the first time. Opened the proj file in my editor, noticed earlier versions of the project HAD the SAK option so I did the reverse of what the answer suggested, putting the SAK into the given tags of this latest upgrade. Worked like a charm, thanx for the help!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with the `*.csproj.user` and if you have source control with the `*.csproj.vspscc` (in VS2012). Delete both, close the solution, close VS, reopen VS using the Run As (preferably administrator) and it should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I would try with removing the previous source control bindings in the .csproj file and then (re-)bind it using **File->Source Control->Change Source Control...**

Comment: there is no such option in VS 2012

Answer (score 4):

In VS2012, Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Section. Change Current source control plug-in.

After moving project from mercurial to GiT, I had the same problem. I change "Current source control plug-in" from Mercucial to VisualHG(which I must install from Extensions cose I don't have this option at start).

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue when someone else added a project to the solution and I got latest in solution. All I did was restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the above worked for me and I was having problems with libraries that were fine in other projects, it was reasonable for me to consider it to be a problem with the solution rather than an individual project.

What worked for me was to open the solution file (.sln) in notepad (taking a backup first just to be safe), and if there is a section:

```
GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
 ...
EndGlobalSection
```

then delete it, save the solution and reopen. Problem fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you are using other tool for source control e.g. source tree for Git and Mercurial, then you can just set Current source control plug-in to None in VS.

*In VS2015, Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Section. Change Current source control plug-in to None.*